# How to changed date format from an API? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, api

I download some info from an API. it has this format    **1657762387**  a whole integer.

How can I convert it the right way?

I tried   **pd.todatetime(df['colum'])** and didn't worked I got some erroneous random date.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need use the `unit` argument

```py
df['colum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colum'], unit='s')
```

```
print(df)

                colum
0 2022-07-14 01:33:07
```